# How do you properly redirect using Remix Forms?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

TL;DR: When I select an item from the drop down it is not redirecting me to the correct page.

I'm making a photo sharing website and I'm using Remix and the url to render all the data on the pages.
Here is a screenshot to give you a better idea:
[Main page draft UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDzFE.jpg)

So when the user selects North America from the Continent drop down menu it will navigate to /north-america and then the Continent menu drop down will have North America selected and the Country drop down menu will display all countries in North America (that exist in my database) as well as the breadcrumbs (breadcrumbs is working) and so on.

Here is the relevant code:

```
export async function loader({ request, params }: LoaderArgs) {
  const [{ data: continents }, { data: countries }, { data: regions }] =
    await Promise.all([
      supabase.from("continents").select("*"),
      supabase.from("countries").select("name, slug, continent( name, slug )"),
      supabase
        .from("regions")
        .select("name, slug, country (name, slug, continent (name, slug)))"),
    ]);

  return json({
    user: await getUser(request),
    continents,
    countries,
    regions,
  });
}

export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
  const body = await request.formData();
  const continent = body.get("continent") as string;
  const country = body.get("country") as string;
  const region = body.get("region") as string;

  const location = continent || country || region || "/";
  const result = redirect(location);
  return result;
}

export default function App() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  const params = useParams();
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const [state, setState] = useState(params);

  function handleChange(event: { currentTarget: FormData }) {
    submit(event.currentTarget, { replace: true });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en" className="h-full">
        <head>
          <Combobox photos={photos} />
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
          <Meta />
          <Links />
        </head>
        <body className="h-full">
          <NavBar />
          <Breadcrumbs location={params} />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-1 md:grid-cols-5">
            <Form method="post" onChange={handleChange}>
              {/* Continent Selector */}
              <div className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl py-10 sm:px-4 lg:px-4">
                <div className="flex-auto pr-10">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="continent"
                    className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Continent
                  </label>
                  <select
                    id="continent"
                    title="continent"
                    name="location"
                    className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 py-2 pl-3 text-base focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                    value={state.continent}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      setState({ Continent: event.target.value })
                    }
                  >
                    <option value="">Select a continent...</option>
                    {data.continents?.map((continent, index) => (
                      <option value={continent.slug} key={index}>
                        {continent.name}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Form>
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I'm very new to react so I'm sure I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: is this your import `import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";` Also can you try `return redirect(location)`

Comment: If you remove the tag information from your post title, it won't be accepted here, which means it is a poor title. Please [edit] your post to add an actually descriptive title that explains the problem you're having. *not working* is useless.